# Recover Facebook app in Developer Center

Tags: facebook

We are in something like... a huge mess!

We have a Facebook app and the Android and iOS version live in their own markets. By accident, the admin of the app in Facebook removed permissions for himself. Is there any way to recover this step? Contacting Facebook or something like that to rollback this change.

We just need to recover the app, that now has gone from developer center (and Android/iOS apps now do not work)

Any help is welcome!

Thank you very much.

Comment: What do you mean he removed permissions for himself? But I would guess the only solution is to file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: @WizKid it's like an accidental "Remove app". Is there any way to recover the app? Praying God? Anything =)

Comment: Like accidentally click Remove app and then click Yes. And I don't think there is a  way to restore but if there is filing a bug would be the only way